# React.Js context and Maximum Depth excedeed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

I get the following error: 
`Unhandled Rejection (Invariant Violation): Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.`

I get this error when i try to run a given mutation, the mutation is

```
<Mutation mutation={LOGIN}>
    { (login, {data,loading,error}) => {
        if(loading)  return(<h1> Loading... </h1>);
        if(data) this.context.login(
            data.login.token, 
            data.login.userId, 
            data.login.tokenExpiration);
        return(
            <button onClick={
                e => {
                e.preventDefault();
                    login({
                        variables: {
                            email: this.state.email,
                            password: this.state.password
                        }
                    })
                }}>
                Login
            </button>
        );
    }}
</Mutation>
```

If i remove the `if(data) login(...)` block above the return it will work fine.

This is the context i'm using
import React from 'react';

```
export default React.createContext({
    token: null,
    userId: null,
    login: (token,userId,tokenExpiration) => {},
    logout: () => {},
});
```

which wraps soem JSX in my main page like

```
<AuthContext.Provider value={
    {
        token: this.state.token, 
        userId: this.state.userId, 
        login: this.login, 
        logout:this.logout
    }
}>
```

the login and logout method are

```
login = (token,userId,tokenExpiration) => {
        this.setState({ token:token, userId: userId });
    }

    logout = () => {
        this.setState({token:null, userId: null});
    }
```

I made 100% percent to import everything right, the graphQL mutation returns the data we want as well. React is telling me the error is inside my login method but i don't see any problem with it. Any ideeas? I am not very experienced with the context api.

Comment: What is `this` in the function child in your `<Mutation>` component? Is this code being returned from a class based component?

Comment: Also, what's the difference between `this.context.login` and the `login` variable being passed as an argument?

Comment: @coreyward Yes, where i use the mutaiton I have a class based component

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with your last question @coreyward

Comment: You shouldn’t call a method that updates state inside a component’s render method. `this.context.login` updates state, which causes the component to rerender, which causes the method to be fired again and so on… The `login` method from your `Mutation` component returns a promise, so just do something like `login(…).then(() => this.context.login(…))`

Comment: @DanielRearden you mean after i call my login function onClick, to add a then and call the context.login?

Comment: Correct, or you can use async/await syntax. The point is, you want to move the method call into the click handler and out of the render method.

Comment: @DanielRearden so what i did was  ```login({
                                        variables: {
                                            email: this.state.email,
                                            password: this.state.password
                                        }
                                    }).then(() => this.context.login(
                                        data.login.token, 
                                        data.login.userId, 
                                        data.login.tokenExpiration))```

Comment: @DanielRearden but it says `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'login' of undefined`

Comment: @DanielRearden i get this because i don't have the data from the GraphQL mutation ( data.login...)

Comment: Let's [continue this in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194650/room-for-daniel-rearden-and-chris).